# How do i export results of a foreach-object with custom object in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, compareobject, foreach-object

I can't seems to be able to export the results of the Foreach in a csv or even a txt file.
It asks me for input or simply a blank file

What the code do is import two csv both with same values but with eventual difference or missing value compare them and return the results

```ps
function compare {

    #Declaring vars
    $csv3 = "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Desktop\file3.csv"
    $csv1 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Desktop\file.csv"
    $csv2 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Desktop\file2.csv"

    #Start of the main block
    echo "Running..."
    Compare-Object $csv1 $csv2 -IncludeEqual -Property Name,Size,Version,FullName,LastWriteTime |
       ForEach-Object {
            If( $R.sideindicator -ne "==" ){
                  [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Name  = ($_.Name)
                    Srv1 = ($_.FullName, $_.Size,$_.LastWriteTime, $_.Version)
                    Srv2 = ($csv2   | Select-object -Property ($_.FullName, $_.Size,$_.LastWriteTime), @{Name="Version";Expression={$_.Version -replace "",'empty'}})

                } 
            }
        }
}
```

This is one of the output

```ps
Name           Srv1                                                                                                 Srv2                                                                                                       
----           ----                                                                                                 ----                                                                                                       
caqs_.exe    \application\caqs_.exe,26,4469604492188,27/01/2020 17:00:23,5, 82, 254, 0 {@{\application\caqs_.exe,26,4469604492188,27/01/2020 17:00:23=; Version=}, @...
```

Now i want to be able to export the same return values above inside a csv, or anything that could keep this format, if i put an export-csv i either have a blank empty csv file or the console will ask me for inputobject.

Comment: CSV files are flat, but your data is nested. What exactly would the resulting CSV look like?

Comment: Maybe not csv but anything that have the same look as the result output

So a name column a srv1 column and srv2 column

Comment: Simple way  :  [system.string]::Join(",", @($Name, $Srv1,$Srv2)) >> test.csv

Comment: This result in a blank csv files, Lines do appear but they're empty

Answer (score 0):

The 'Compare-Object' cmdlet returns properties, 'InputObject','SideIndicator'.
I believe the properties you are wanting to access are nested inside the 'InputObject' property.
For example, instead of `$_.FullName`, you'll want to use `$_.InputObject.FullName`.

Or you could simplify the script and do something like this:

```
(Compare-Object $csv1 $csv2 -IncludeEqual -Property Name,Size,Version,FullName,LastWriteTime | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -ne "=="}).InputObject | Export-Csv $csv3 -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it's not the desired results.

issue is it displays only one sided comparison and the need is to be able to have both values from the two files next to each other similar to the first output i posted

current output with what you gave looks like this :

`"Name","Size","Version","FullName","LastWriteTime","SideIndicator"
"archive","9,5367431640625E-07","","\appl\caqs\archive","22/06/2021 13:13:42","=>" `